# How do I turn a row into a map?

Tags: pandas

Rows used to be able to work as maps for string interpolation, like this:

```
from pandas import *

speeds = read_csv('results.csv')
row = speeds.ix[3]
print("%(my_column_name)s" % row)
```

that worked a few months ago, but doesn't seem to work in the latest Pandas.  How can I turn a row into a map, or otherwise do simple & concise custom printing of rows?

Comment: This will get you a map: `speeds.ix[3].to_dict()`

Comment: @Zelazny7 you should make that an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will convert to a map: `speeds.ix[3].to_dict()`